# LNK1106 with big binary resource

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, linker

I have a rather huge .dat-file (896MB) included as a BIN resource in my project. Now I get a LNK1106 link error ("fatal error LNK1106: invalid file or disk full: cannot seek to 0x382A3920".)
I use Visual Studio 2005 under Windows XP, and have tried on a 4GB RAM machine with high Virtual Memory settings and lots of disk space. 
I have tried a number of different optimization flags, but to no avail.

Does anyone have a clue?

EDIT: I have narrowed it down to a specific size of the compiled resource. If the .res file is 544078588 bytes (about 518.9MB) or larger, the error occurs. If it is smaller it works just fine. Still no solution, though...

Comment: The offset in binary is 898 MB. Hence, the linker is clearly seeking beyond the end of the file, by ~2MB. No idea why, but the message makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Under "Additional Linker Options", add `/expectedoutputsize:600000000`, and the link will work like a charm. You can't go too far with that switch though, or you'll end up with:

> FATAL : link error LNK1102: out of memory

Comment: Where in this world can I add `/expectedoutputsize:600000000` I can't find this place in the project settings?!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing /OPT:IFC to /OPT:NOIFC.  Can't tell you why it works.  Your results may vary.

Comment: Thanks for the input! It does not seem to make any difference for me, though... ;-\
Here is my link command line: /VERBOSE:LIB /OUT:"NoDebug/MyProgram.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"MyLib_release\win\lib" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"NoDebug\MyProgram.exe.intermediate.manifest" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /OPT:REF /OPT:NOICF /LTCG /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT MyLib.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

Answer (score 0):

Is the dat file generated or has it changed recently? Your program may be trying to link against an incorrect version.

Comment: Well, it clear that it uses the correct file. When I substitute it for a smaller file, the linking is successful. Trying out smaller files now to see if I can find a magic size...