# fatal error LNK1106: invalid file or disk full: cannot seek to 0x5A57BEBC

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, configuration, linker

I got this error using Visual Studio 2008 and I found a solution on the web [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742568/lnk1106-with-big-binary-resource) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888326). But I can't find out how to configure `link.exe`.

How can I set the `/expectedoutputsize:600000000` option for `linker.exe` in `VS2008`? I searched in the project properties in the `Linker` section, but I can't find the place...I searched in the solution and in Visual Studio options. I found the linker.exe.config but I don't know the schema.

My problem is not the disk space, I have plenty of disk space. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option must be added in the `Project Settings->Librarian->Command Line->Additional options:` text box.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to resurrect this old thread, but I had a similar problem yesterday, and my solution had nothing to do with anything I found online. This is the first SO post that comes up, so I figured I would contribute in case anyone as the same problem.

**Here is how I ran into the problem:**

I originally had a project that created an exe:

- MyProject.vcxproj -> MyProject.exe

I then turned the original project in to a .lib project by splitting main.cpp out to a separate .exe project. I set the target name for the exe project to be the same as the lib, so that we wouldn't change our executable name. I also added a different .exe project that uses the library but has a slightly different main.cpp

- MyProject.vcxproj -> MyProject.lib
- MyProjectVariant1.vcxproj -> MyProject.exe
- MyProjectVariant2.vcxproj -> MyProjectVariant2.exe

The way our solution is currently laid out, all of the projects dump their targets into the same output directory.

The problem was that both the .lib and first .exe share the same target name, so any secondary files (pdb files, iobj, ipdb, etc.) would get overwritten. MyProject.exe would literally overwrite these ancillary files before it could link in the MyProject.lib.

**Conclusion:**

I "fixed" the problem by using a unique target name for the first variant. We will also review our build strategy to see if we should be using different output directories for each project instead of slamming them all together in the same location. Seems more logical to give them different target directories.