# Node addon compilation error

Tags: c++, node.js, compiler-errors, node-modules, node-nan

I am new to creating c++ addons for node.
I've instaled windows-build-tools and after running `node-gyp build` I've encountered a strange problem.

I tryed to do some research before asking this question but it seams there is no clear answer.

I've also tryed reinstaling node-gyp and build tools.

My question is what is the cause of this problem and how to fix it

```
node-gyp build
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@9.5.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]
Projekty w tym rozwiązaniu są tworzone po kolei. Aby umożliwić tworzenie równoległe, dodaj przełącznik "/m".
C:\Users\maciek\.node-gyp\9.5.0\x64\node.lib : fatal error LNK1106: invalid file or disk full: cannot seek to 0x1E5CBE [C:\Users\maci
ek\Desktop\mcn\build\myModule.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\maciek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\maciek\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\maciek\Desktop\mcn
gyp ERR! node -v v9.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have a free space on your disk (simply clear it),or you put an invalid build file path.

Comment: I have 2 partitions each of them has more than 100GB

Comment: `fatal error LNK1106: invalid file or disk full.` node.lib mind be: missing, corrupt, or you are building with another architecture. For example node.js is 32 bit, when your library is 64 bit or vise versa.

Comment: Take a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155492/how-do-i-specify-the-platform-for-msbuild

Comment: @VictorGubin I've checked node.lib also I've reinstaled node-gyp. It also creates a project so it should be valid. I'm building x64 and node.lib matches

Comment: Ok, got it. Take a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702613/fatal-error-lnk1106-invalid-file-or-disk-full-cannot-seek-to-0x5a57bebc

Comment: Added /expectedoutputsize:600000000 as linker arg but it didn't help :/

Comment: One more thing. Looks like there were some caches  or whatever https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild/issues/163

Comment: Actualy I'm not using electron, just nan to create c++ addon

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It was resolved through following steps

Step 1 Make sure Phython is installed and has path installed in system variable

try npm install now

If it does now work proceed to step two

Step 2 Delete .node-gyp folder and install node-gyp again